# VIM doesn't start from inside a Python virtual environment

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, youcompleteme, vundle

I am normally able to use vim without any issues. But whenever I try to start it from inside a python virtual environment (both Conda and virtualenv), I get a segmentation fault.

I have identified that it is because of the `Valloric\YouCompleteMe` plugin. When I comment out the corresponding lines from my `.vimrc` everything works as expected.

I use YCM a lot in my workflow and would love to find a solution where I can use it with virtual environments.

The relevant lines in my `.vimrc` are as follows :

```
Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
"*****other plugins follow
call vundle#end()

" You Complete Me
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1
map <leader>g  :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Robᵩ I am using macOS

Comment: What about opening a defect against YCM?

Comment: @dlmeetei Did you mean creating an issue into YCM repo? I was not sure if it is due to some mistake on my side.

Comment: That's right. May be you can confirm that first then by loading into debugger first. Tend to believe it will be mostly YCM as commenting that out plugins stopped the crash

Comment: @dlmeetei Thanks. This is how the log looks like :
 `YouCompleteMe unavailable: dlopen(/Users/<uname>/Programming/<project_root>/<venv_name>/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /Users/<uname>/Programming/<project_root>/<venv_name>/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/<uname>/Programming/<project_root>/<venv_name>/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so`

Comment: It seems like there was some issue with the vim in macOS channel being outdated. I used brew to get macVim and aliased vim to use mvim -v and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is because of incompatibility with the macOS's default vim.

To fix it, use `brew` to install macVim. Now, you can use the `vim` app in macVim to get everything started again.

```
brew install macvim
alias vim="mvim -v"
```